# numpy array from nested iteraror/generator with string elements

Tags: python, numpy, iterator, generator, sympy

How can I convert nested iterator with string elements to numpy array? Which `dtype` should be used?

```
from sympy.utilities.iterables import variations
x=variations(["H","T"],3, True)
np.fromiter(x, dtype=string)
```

Comment: np.array(list(x))?

Comment: `np.fromiter(x, 'U3,U3,U3')` also works.  `fromiter` creates/expects a 1d array/sequence.